# Repeating Static Tablix On Each Page

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, reportbuilder, ssrs-2017

I am trying to setup a "bookmark" menu table as a side bar on my SSRS report with text that links to bookmarks as different sections on the report. The bookmark menu will be looking as such:

[image]

I want to repeat this tablix one each page of my report. Is there an easy and better way to do it than just by pasting it separately at each section of the report?

I am also thinking of adding the breadcrumbs as part of the header, but there is a project requirement to have it as a sidebar on the report. Please let me know if you have ideas on how i can do that easily without having to copy paste it on every page as that seems like bad design. Moreover, if i have to make updates , i would have to do it in several places.

Comment: have you considered just using a document map? Simple to implement and exists outside the main report area so no issues with repeating on pages etc.

Answer (score 0):

The only possibility to repeat the tablix automatically on each page is in the header or footer.

The other option is to copy the tablix on each page. This is not very resonable, because of changes that can happen in the future (maintainability).

The best option is like @Alan Schofield mentioned a document map. Maybe this tutorial will help you [Document Map Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sYLN96l8kqo)

Comment: Thanks! the document map is a good method... i tried it with the header but the only issue i see there is that when you go to a bookmark it jumps under the header and displays.. so a user has to scroll back up to view the header.. but i guess these are the best options